# How do you get an NPC out of your house in terraria

Tags: terraria

How do you get Timmy out of your house in terraria, I’ve tried heaps of times to get an arms dealer but Timmy (who btw is the fish fanatic) takes it before the dealer comes, PLUES HE STOLE MY ROOM

Comment: https://terraria.gamepedia.com/House#Housing_Menu

Answer (score 2):

You can make another room and then an NPC will move in. If you don't get an arms dealer if you do this, just try again.

Answer (score 1):

Build more rooms/houses. There are a lot of NPCs that will show up, so an arms dealer may not be the next to spawn if you build a second house, so build a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

the hard way: Fill the house with blocks and build another house, the angler will move out (make sure the previous house is smaller). After 1 or so days, the arms dealer should move in

the easy way: Build a separate house

Answer (score 0):

There is a single way of getting him in, but requires some things.

1. An empty house.
2. A bullet or bullet-firing gun in the player's inventory.

If nor of these two conditions are met(e.g. there's not an empty house and the player dosen't have an bullet or bullet-firing gun in their inventory), he won't come.

A good way to get him is stopping from beating bosses/starting events and building a lot of houses so he will come in. Stopping adventuring may be necessary, as some NPC's appear when bosses/events are beaten, and so may take the houses available. When the Arms Dealer comes in, you can start beating bosses/events again. Just be sure there's always an empty house and that you have a bullet in the inventory.

Hope i helped you.